# Working with Sharepoint from MS Access

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

Afternoon,

My company makes use of Microsofts Sharepoint facility to organize documents and such; we also use Sharepoint to hold project specific resources used by multiple people.

**Question**

Is it possible to access Sharepoint from within MS Access? I don't mean open it, I mean actually writing to or reading from files that are stored on it? If it's possible is there a particular module I should read up on or am required to import into any projects? (Example code or related resource would be appreciated)

**Potential Use Case**

Employee A makes a change to a table in a database (adding a record) which may be required by Employee B in the future. Employee B should be-able to retrieve it directly from Sharepoint without having to open a browser, download the file and manually add the table.

Thanks for any information you can give me as I know this is an odd one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint does have MS Access integration.  You can setup access to use SharePoint lists as their datasource, allowing you to edit the data from Access or from the browser.

This **[link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/build-and-publish-an-access-database-to-sharepoint-HA102435342.aspx)** provides some video tutorials on how to publish an Access web database to SharePoint. Essentially you create and edit the database in Access and you publish to SharePoint.  This works well for simple databases, but it doesn't work as well for more complex databases.

Comment: thanks for the reply mate - i'll accept this when i investigate it some more